# awk logical operator

Tags: awk, logical-operators

I have two questions to ask. I'll number it in order. Please consider them while answering.

1. is `i%2!=0` different from `!(i%2)`.
   I was working on an awk expression and was getting different outputs while interchanging these.

`awk 'BEGIN{OFS=";"}!(NR%2){printf p,$0;}{p=$0}'` gives me desired output but

`awk 'BEGIN{OFS=";"}(NR%2!=0){printf p,$0;}{p=$0}'` gives something else. What is wrong here??

Comment: Never write `printf var` (for any input data) as it'll fail cryptically when `var` contains printf formatting chars, use `printf "%s", var` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!(NR%2)` is like `(NR%2)==0`, or `NR%2==0`. It is the opposite of `NR%2!=0`, which explains why you are getting different outputs.